# Calculate length of spaces image of text

Tags: math

I am currently extracting letters from an image to write a letter recognizer using a convolutional neural network.
The information I get from the image of text is the position of each letter on the image itself.
What I am trying to do is determine where a word ends so I can insert a space when I am printing my result. 
A line break is quite easy since the distance from the current letter to the next letter is negative and that's how I determine a line break.
Now to determine if there is a space between 2 letters doesn't seem that easy.

Things I have tried:

1. Set a threshold (30 pixels)

   - Worked for very specific texts
2. Calculate a mean of all distances excluding negative ones

   - Worked only for specific texts as well

Is anyone aware of a standardized way to determine if there is a space between 2 letters on an image of text? (This should be independent of font and such)

Comment: I think you're severely underestimating the complexity of this problem. For one, it is clearly not the case that a line break can be detected by a negative horizontal shift. What if I indicate the start of paragraphs by indenting them, as is common, and the last line of the paragraph happens to be very short? If the last line is shorter than the indentation that opens the next paragraph, your algorithm breaks. You won't be able to sit down and solve this problem for scratch.

Comment: Yes you are right, this could be solved by taking the y coordinate of the letter into account if I am not mistaken, the issue with the space still remains tho.